# Are the Share related badges available in Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: support, feature-request, badges, stack-overflow-enterprise

In the public Stack there are three badges related to sharing URLs: Announcer,  Booster and Publicist. These don't appear to be available in our Stack Overflow Enterprise implementation.

- Other Badges in Public Stack:

  [image]
- Other Badges in Stack Overflow Enterprise:

  [image]

The URL in our Share modal has the userid at the end, but I don't see the badges or any reports in the moderator area related to sharing.

So I would like know:

- Were they added to a release that is newer than what we have?
- Are they configurable and we chose not to use them?
- Do they not exist in SOE and there is a technical reason?
- Or, do they not exist yet, and this can serve as a feature request?

Comment: Do you expect to have your Enterprise site visited by external readers? If not, there's not much point in having those badges.

Comment: No external readers, but there is a huge opportunity for sharing internally. I share Q and A all the time to draw co-workers into Stack. Part of the purpose is to build an employee knowledge base and we want to get as much usage as possible. Badges are just one more incentive to participate.

Comment: I imagine the main problem is that it can't differentiate between IPs. It's an enterprise version after all, most of the time it's used is going to be at work, which usually means a single IP.

Comment: Doesn't it track the IP of the page visitor? Every networked workstation will have its own unique IP address. And every user has to authenticate, so we know who is visiting pages already.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  [tag:support] questions about Stack Overflow Enterprise are outside of the scope of Meta Stack Overflow per precedent at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416722/3750257.